# Looking for optimisation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, query-optimization

I have created some APIs using node js and mongodb.
I have below api which I am using for updating user profile.
User can update any information at any time
for example name, bio information, phone number.
I'm passing this user data as query parameters e.g if user wants to update name and phone then the query would look like below

```
http://localhost:3000/users/updateUserByEmail?name=some name&phone=00000
```

And in another scenario if user wants to update name bio information phone then query would look like below

```
http://localhost:3000/users/updateUserByEmail?name=some name&phone=00000&bioInfo= some bio
```

Below is the code I'm using to achieve above scenario and I thinks it's not the optimised way to do

```
const updateUserByEmail = async (req, res, next) => {
  let { email, name, phone, bioInfo } = req.query;
  try {
    const user = await Users.find({ email: email });
    name = name || user[0].name;
    phone = phone || user[0].phone;
    bioInfo = bioInfo || user[0].bioInfo;

    const updatedUser = await Users.updateOne(
      { email },
      { $set: { name, phone, bioInfo } }
    );
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Updated Successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json( error );
  }
};
```

Looking for optimised code suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Sequelize? It's not clear what `Users` is.

Comment: Why do you think it is not the optimized way? The operation is so simple, there is not much you can do, maybe apart from using `findAndModify`

Comment: @tadman Users  is mongodb model

Comment: It's not clear why you're doing the `find()` first. You aren't returning the object and `update` already ignores fields that are already `$set` to the requested value. So you could save a trip to the database there (similar to the `findAndModify` suggestion above). And if you have an index on `email` then I'm not sure there's anything else to improve here. Well the `find()` could have been a `findOne()`, but that's irrelevant if you get rid of it altogether